# Liquid - Split values separated by comma into a bullet list

Tags: liquid, liquid-layout

I have a few variables that I want to use in liquid:

customer id

list of property names (contain multiple values separated by a comma)

list of property id (contain multiple values separated by a comma)

I would like to end up with something that says

"customer ID has pricing expiring for the following properties

list of property names (split by comma and separated by a bullet point on multiple lines)

list of property id (split by comma and separated by a bullet point on multiple lines)

I've never used liquid so would really appreciate any help :)

Cheers!

I have tried a few different ways of doing this, mainly using chat gpt, but nothing gets close to what I want to achieve